# How to use Order By in a stored procedure without using dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

I've the following MS SQL stored procedure. I need to sort the results without using dynamic SQL and `sp_executesql` method

@Order by can have the possible values `ProductName ASC`, `ProductName DESC`, `ProductCode ASC`, `VendorName DESC`, `VendorCode` or `ClientName`

I was trying to use `ORDER BY CASE`, is there any issue if the  `ProductName`, `ProductCode` are of different type?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SortedReport]
(
    @ClientID INT,
    @RecordLimit,
    @FromDate DATETIME,
    @ToDate DATETIME,
    @OrderBy NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

AS
BEGIN

IF (@OrderBy IS NULL) BEGIN
    SET @OrderBy = 'ProductName';
END    

SELECT TOP (@RecordLimit) 
        sv.ClientID,
        sv.VendorID,
        sv.ProductID,
        sv.TransactionTime,
        sv.ClientName,
        sv.VendorName,
        sv.ProductName,
        sv.ProductCode,
        sv.VendorCode,
FROM SortedReportiew AS sv 
WHERE (sv.ClientID = @ClientID)
    AND (sv.TransactionTime >= @FromDate)
    AND (sv.TransactionTime < @Date)
```

**Update:**

Is the below part correct? ref from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/dynamicvsstatic2/623/)

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'ProductCode ASC' THEN ProductCode WHEN 'ProductCode DESC' THEN ProductCode END DESC,
    CASE @OrderBy WHEN 'ProductName ASC' THEN ProductName WHEN 'ProductName DESC' THEN ProductName END DESC,
```

Comment: Why not dynamic SQL?  It's much faster than any of the static solutions for this kind of problem.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid dynamic SQL to run a dynamic statement?

Comment: @RBarryYoung , @Markus Winand , simply because client want to convert those dynamic SQL's to static

Comment: So, ask the client why to do that ;) There is the "[dynamic SQL is slow myth](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/dynamic-sql-is-slow)" that leads many times to requests like this. However, correctly done dynamic-sql (using bind-paramters) is typically better.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: getting rid of dynamic sql for "order by" results in better performance across these order by queries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you already said: Use `ORDER BY CASE`, but multiple times to avoid the problems with different column types:

```
...
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='ProductName ASC' THEN sv.ProductName END,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='ProductName DESC' THEN sv.ProductName END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='ProductCode ASC' THEN sv.ProductCode END,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='ProductCode DESC' THEN sv.ProductCode END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='VendorName ASC' THEN sv.VendorName END,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='VendorName DESC' THEN sv.VendorName END DESC,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='VendorCode' THEN sv.VendorCode END,
 CASE WHEN @OrderBy ='ClientName' THEN sv.ClientName END
```

**EDIT:**

Updated the query to fit your updated question. I assume you meant `ProductCode ASC` **and** `ProductCode DESC`?

Comment: Please see updated question, @OrderBy contains sort direction too like `ProductName ASC`

Comment: ASC/DESC is optional, with ASC being the default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I understand, the ordering uses just one column. In that case I might try something like this:

1. Split `@OrderBy` into `@OrderByCol` and `@OrderByDir`.
2. Use this template:

   ```
   ...
   ORDER BY
     CASE @OrderByDir WHEN 'ASC' THEN
       CASE @OrderByCol
         WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1
         WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2
         ...
       END
     END ASC,

     CASE @OrderByDir WHEN 'DESC' THEN
       CASE @OrderByCol
         WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1
         WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2
         ...
       END
     END DESC
   ```

   Or, if you are on SQL Server 2005+, maybe this one, as an alternative:

   ```
   WITH sorted AS (
     SELECT
        ... /* columns, omitted */
        Column1Order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1),
        Column2Order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column2),
        ...
     FROM ...
   )
   SELECT ...
   FROM sorted
   ORDER BY
     CASE @OrderByCol
       WHEN 'Column1' THEN Column1Order
       WHEN 'Column2' THEN Column2Order
       ...
     END * CASE @OrderByDir WHEN 'DESC' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
   ```

As @Greg Ogle has correctly pointed out in the comment, the first template can only work when the various sorting criteria are of compatible types, otherwise the statement will break.

Comment: Note that the ORDER BY's must be of the same data type per CASE, otherwise it will get a conversion error.

Comment: Thanks, I added the note to my answer (don't know why I failed to do so when I was posting the answer).